# Software failing to install on Windows XP

Tags: installation, setup-deployment

I have developed a C# software on Visual Studio 2015, using Visual Studio installer for the setup.

One of our customers complained about being unable to install the software on Windows XP, immediately getting an error Windows "The installer was interrupted before VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 could be installed. Your need to restart the installer again".

I could reproduce the problem on an old XP machine and generate a log using msiexec. However I'm not very familiar with this and I'm unable to understand what is the problem. Can somebody help me to interpretate what is going wrong ?

Thank you for your assistance on this.

```
=== Verbose logging started: 27/10/2017  09:47:13  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 4.05.6001.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:13:794]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:13:794]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:13:794]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:13:813]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:017]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:017]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi has a digital signature
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:573]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:647]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:647]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:665]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:665]: Original package ==> C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:665]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Temp\40d6a.msi
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:684]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{57956046-D7F1-4620-BE3C-DE78A4ECF10E}'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:702]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:777]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{57956046-D7F1-4620-BE3C-DE78A4ECF10E}'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\MyLogFile.txt'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=4904 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{2B1B8EC8-971E-4875-AEA8-4CA7D29CFB1C}'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{57956046-D7F1-4620-BE3C-DE78A4ECF10E}'
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{57956046-D7F1-4620-BE3C-DE78A4ECF10E}'
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Package name extracted from package path: 'VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi'
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Package to be registered: 'VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi'
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: Running product '{57956046-D7F1-4620-BE3C-DE78A4ECF10E}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '4904'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Application Data
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Favorites
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\NetHood
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\My Documents
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\PrintHood
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Recent
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\SendTo
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Templates
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Local Settings\Application Data
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\My Documents\My Pictures
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Start Menu
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:925]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Desktop
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:943]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Templates
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:943]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:14:943]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:036]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:036]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'DEV'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:036]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding COMPANYNAME property. Its value is 'Bureau Veritas'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:036]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\Temp\40d6a.msi'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:036]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:036]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:036]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:036]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\'.
MSI (c) (28:40) [09:47:15:870]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '4.05'.
=== Logging started: 27/10/2017  09:47:15 ===
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:888]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:888]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:888]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:888]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:888]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:888]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:15:888]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
Action 09:47:16: INSTALL. 
Action start 09:47:16: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:16:074]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:16:074]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:16:074]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:16:074]: Doing action: DIRCA_CheckFX
Action 09:47:16: DIRCA_CheckFX. 
Action start 09:47:16: DIRCA_CheckFX.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:16:222]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'DIRCA_CheckFX' 
MSI (c) (28:AC) [09:47:16:278]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Temp\MSI3.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckFX
MSI (c) (28:7C) [09:47:16:278]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (28:7C) [09:47:16:278]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (28:7C) [09:47:16:278]: Connected to service for CA interface.
Action ended 09:47:16: DIRCA_CheckFX. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:16:518]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 09:47:16: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 09:47:16: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:16:667]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
MSI (c) (28:40) [09:47:16:667]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (28:40) [09:47:16:685]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
MSI (c) (28:40) [09:47:16:685]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
MSI (c) (28:40) [09:47:16:685]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
MSI (c) (28:40) [09:47:16:685]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898. For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (28:40) [09:47:16:685]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.
Action 09:47:16: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
MSI (c) (28:F4) [09:47:16:704]: Note: 1: 2731 2: 0 
Action ended 09:47:21: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.
Action ended 09:47:21: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:670]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (28:7C) [09:47:21:670]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {DB1E5694-A4A3-4C3D-BC8A-0E33D8C1F6EA}
Property(C): SourceDir = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(C): VSDFrameworkVersion = v4.6.1
Property(C): VSDAllowLaterFrameworkVersions = False
Property(C): ProductName = VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3
Property(C): ProductCode = {57956046-D7F1-4620-BE3C-DE78A4ECF10E}
Property(C): ProductVersion = 3.0.3
Property(C): Manufacturer = Bureau Veritas
Property(C): ARPCONTACT = Bureau Veritas
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(C): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(C): ARPPRODUCTICON = _112D608FD02CD87FDC7735.exe
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED;NEWERPRODUCTFOUND
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): VersionNT = 502
Property(C): VSDNETURLMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?
Property(C): VSDIISMSG = This setup requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or higher and Windows XP or higher.  This setup cannot be installed on Windows 2000.  Please install Internet Information Server or a newer operating system and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic.
Property(C): VSDNETMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = The specified path '[2]' is unavailable. The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager.
Property(C): VSDVERSIONMSG = Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed.
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog
Property(C): SFF_UpFldrBtn = UpFldrBtn
Property(C): SFF_NewFldrBtn = NewFldrBtn
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_Property = No
Property(C): AdminMaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(C): MaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(C): FolderForm_AllUsers = ME
Property(C): FolderForm_AllUsersVisible = 1
Property(C): EulaForm_Property = No
Property(C): DefaultUIFont = VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400
Property(C): AdminWelcomeForm_NextArgs = AdminEulaForm
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_PrevArgs = AdminWelcomeForm
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_NextArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(C): AdminFolderForm_PrevArgs = AdminEulaForm
Property(C): AdminFolderForm_NextArgs = AdminConfirmInstallForm
Property(C): AdminConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(C): WelcomeForm_NextArgs = EulaForm
Property(C): EulaForm_PrevArgs = WelcomeForm
Property(C): EulaForm_NextArgs = FolderForm
Property(C): FolderForm_PrevArgs = EulaForm
Property(C): FolderForm_NextArgs = ConfirmInstallForm
Property(C): ConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = FolderForm
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\MyLogFile.txt
Property(C): PackageCode = {2B1B8EC8-971E-4875-AEA8-4CA7D29CFB1C}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 4904
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(C): VersionMsi = 4.05
Property(C): VersionNT64 = 502
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 3790
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 2
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(C): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = C:\Temp\
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(C): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(C): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Application Data\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Favorites\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\NetHood\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\My Documents\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\PrintHood\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Templates\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\Local Settings\Application Data\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\My Documents\My Pictures\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(C): Msix64 = 6
Property(C): Intel = 6
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 12287
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 29205
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): LogonUser = odegrand
Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-2680509306-2404333407-1988928202-135417
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 1036
Property(C): ComputerName = WXPSMS01DEVODE
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1036
Property(C): ScreenX = 1920
Property(C): ScreenY = 1200
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 26
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 32
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 09:47:21
Property(C): Date = 27/10/2017
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.1
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 5.2.3790.3959
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): USERNAME = DEV
Property(C): COMPANYNAME = Bureau Veritas
Property(C): DATABASE = C:\Temp\40d6a.msi
Property(C): OriginalDatabase = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 setup.msi
Property(C): SOURCEDIR = C:\Documents and Settings\odegrand\
Property(C): VersionHandler = 4.05
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
=== Logging stopped: 27/10/2017  09:47:21 ===
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:689]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:689]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:689]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:689]: Product: VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3 -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:689]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: VeriSTAR Lashing 3.0r3. Product Version: 3.0.3. Product Language: 1033. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:707]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:707]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (28:58) [09:47:21:707]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 27/10/2017  09:47:21 ===
```

Comment: Is your product supported on Windows XP? Apparently it looks your application is targeting .Net Framework 4.6.1 but Windows XP do not support 4.5 and onward: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp/